# How to capture 3rd party web service xml from client end programmatically

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf

i often call 3rd party web service that may be developed by classic web service `(ASMX) or WCF`. i just add their web service reference from my VS IDE and when we call that web service from my end then a xml is generated and posted to web service url. when i need to capture what xml the web service posting to web service url then i need to use fiddler but i need to capture out going xml programmatically.

i do not know how can i capture it programmatically from client side. i need a easy solution for capturing whatever technology is used to develop web service. i want to hook from out side so a event will fire when web service will be called and from that event i should be able to get whole xml.looking for help in details. thanks

Comment: Have a look at the [Web Service Discovery Tool (disco)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cy2a3ybs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Maybe you could try to use the command programmatically? AFAIK Visual Studio uses the disco tool to create the Web Service reference from within the GUI (VS solution).

Comment: may be web service could develop with wcf then how to capture programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single extension point to get any outgoing SOAP. You could build your own proxy and force all messages to go through it but there will be a performance hit and general overhead. However each framework has its own extension point. You can implement each one and then call a single interface which handles both. For example, in WCF you can implement your trace listener to receive messages about outgoing SOAP. See [sample here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx). Make the log look like this:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
                 <add name="messages"
                 type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                 initializeData="c:\logs\messages.svclog" />
          </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>

<system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics>
    <messageLogging 
         logEntireMessage="true" 
         logMalformedMessages="false"
         logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" 
         logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
         maxMessagesToLog="3000"
         maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
  </diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
```

and put your own class instead of System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener.

Comment: Should i add the whole xml at client side what u gave here. Does it work for asmx too?

Comment: yes adds all of it. this will not work for asmx. I think there you will need to use SoapExtension

Comment: Thanks for your reply.if i add the above xml then there will be any performance issuu ?

Comment: yes, logging full messages will always slow performance, especially if you have many calls. you will need to test and see if this has a meaningful affect.

Comment: In real life how people log incoming and out going xml?

Comment: this depends on the exact need. if you want to log the message on the wire (it may be encrypted and you can't read it - but depends on your config) you can use WCF logging like above. No need to implement custom logging class, this was just for the need you described to have a single point for all kind of logs. If you want to log the logical message (it shows you all the values the client sent but in terms of security may not be 1x1 like on the wire) then use IClientMessageInspector class and write your logs to disk or db.

Comment: If you do not expect huge amounts of data you should be fine. Like anywhere in your application, if you expect many messages and you see a perfromance affect or disk consumption you should decide if you just want to log a few of the messages, invest in storage and more.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the 3rd party service is an old asmx web service or a WCF service, you can consume them both using a WCF client. That said, if you use WCF it's easy to capture the outgoing and incoming messages.

What you need is a WCF extension point called a Message Inspector. Check this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733786(v=vs.110).aspx

It will allow you to attach a behavior to a WCF endpoint that will give you access to the outgoing and incoming messages of the WCF client. Since it will be your Message Inspector, you will be able to do whatever you want with the message - logging it, changing it in any way you want, etc'.

Comment: It depends. How much traffic goes through your service? how big are the messages?  Naturally it will not ***improve*** your service performance, but the impact can be negligible if done right with the appropriate tools.

Answer (score 1):

If Fiddler meets your needs, you can actually integrate Fiddler's core engine into your code and capture things that way.  This library can be found at http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore

Comment: Is there any sample code like how to integrate fiddler core in my project.